# Center aligned paragraph balanced width lines

Tags: html, css

I have a paragraph with some text in it. The `<p>` has `text-align:center;`. Imagine that the text is bigger than one line. The linebreak is always placed leaving all the posible words in the first line, and just a few in the second line.

Screenshot example:

[image]

And here is a screenshot of how I would like my html/css to position the breaklines:

[image]

Since the text is dynamic, and the page is to be responsive, I dont want to do this by hardcoding `<br>`s or wrapping the text into `<span style="display:inline-block;">`s to define preferred linebreaks. I wouldn't like to change the `font-size` either

Is there any trick to do this automatically without JavaScript?

Comment: Without JS? Most likely not. CSS has no mechanism to count characters or to break lines arbitrarily. Is wrapping the inner content in a separate responsive element not an option?

Comment: I agree with @disinfor, this is not possible with css.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by adding left and right padding.  `padding: 0 50px;` but without using javascript this would pretty much be your only option.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="container">
    <p>
        Text text Text text Text text Text text Text text Text text text Text text Text text Text text Text text Text text text Text text Text text Text text Text text Text text text Text text Text text Text text Text text Text text text Text text Text text Text text Text text Text text text Text text Text text Text text Text text Text text text Text text Text text Text text Text text Text text text Text text Text text Text text Text text Text text
    </p>
</div>

.container {
    font-size: 18px;
    padding:0 20%;
    text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .container {
        padding: 0 20px;
    }
}
```

live demo - https://jsfiddle.net/grinmax_/hLzko135/